# Ant build success even syntaxx error

Tags: java, ant, build, drools

I am using Drools DroolsCompilerAntTask to build the packages binary files such as below

```
 <taskdef name="compiler" classname="org.drools.contrib.DroolsCompilerAntTask" classpathref="drools.path" />

  <target name="rules" >
    <compiler
      binformat="package" 
      srcdir="${path}/src/rules"
      tofile="${path}/build/rules.pkg"
      classpathref="compile.classpath" >
      <include name="*.drl" />
      <include name="*.brl" />
      <include name="*.xml" />
    </compiler>
  </target>
```

But when I run the build. I was able to get the error message and even with the error the build is still showing successful.

```
rule-clean:
rules:
 [compiler] [8,0]: [ERR 107] Line 8:0 mismatched input 'asdasd' expecting one of the following tokens: '[package, import, global, declare, function, rule, query]'.
 [compiler] [0,0]: Parser returned a null Package
 [compiler] [8,0]: [ERR 107] Line 8:0 mismatched input 'asdasd' expecting one of the following tokens: '[package, import, global, declare, function, rule, query]'.
 [compiler] [0,0]: Parser returned a null Package

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 41 seconds
```

Is there any solution to get the Build to Fail when the drool compiler fails?

Comment: What version of drools are you using?

Comment: 5.4.0.Final from the drools repo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reviewing the source code of the [org.drools.contrib.DroolsCompilerAntTask](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/droolsjbpm-tools/blob/5.4.x/drools-ant/src/main/java/org/drools/contrib/DroolsCompilerAntTask.java) you are using, I think I know what's going on. Unfortunately, this seems to be a bug in this class.

By design (we can argue whether this is a good design or a bad one), Drools compiler will not fail (throw any exception) when one of the resources being compiled contains errors. The output you are seeing in your console is indeed the compilation errors found by the compiler, but that doesn't mean that the compiler itself failed. In Drools, after you compile some resources, you need to manually check if there were some errors or not.

The class  [org.drools.contrib.DroolsCompilerAntTask](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/droolsjbpm-tools/blob/5.4.x/drools-ant/src/main/java/org/drools/contrib/DroolsCompilerAntTask.java) uses 2 methods to compile the resources:

- [void compileAndAddFiles(KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder)](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/droolsjbpm-tools/blob/5.4.x/drools-ant/src/main/java/org/drools/contrib/DroolsCompilerAntTask.java#L215)
- [void compileAndAddFiles(PackageBuilder pbuilder)](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/droolsjbpm-tools/blob/5.4.x/drools-ant/src/main/java/org/drools/contrib/DroolsCompilerAntTask.java#L239) (I think this is the one your task is actually using)

Both methods, after they finished compiling the resources you have specified will indeed check for errors; the only problem here is that, if there were compilation errors, they are just printed out to the console and nothing else. No exception is never thrown in this situation. For example, this is how [void compileAndAddFiles(PackageBuilder pbuilder)](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/droolsjbpm-tools/blob/5.4.x/drools-ant/src/main/java/org/drools/contrib/DroolsCompilerAntTask.java#L239) deals with errors:

```
if (pbuilder.hasErrors()) {
    System.err.println(pbuilder.getErrors().toString());
}
```

I guess that the best option you have here is to clone `droolsjbpm-tools` project (use branch `5.4.x`) and add after the `System.err.println` statements in the mentioned methods a `throw new IllegalStateException()` or something like that. The [code that is actually invoking](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/droolsjbpm-tools/blob/5.4.x/drools-ant/src/main/java/org/drools/contrib/DroolsCompilerAntTask.java#L159) the `compileAndAddFiles()` methods is actually catching any exception and wrapping it with a `BuildException`. I'm not an Ant expert, but I think that should be enough to make the task fail.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I was wondering why the error persist while the drools compile with error and still make the build to pass.